# find the limit of $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0 } \frac{a}{x}\left[ {\frac{x}{b}} \right]$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

$$a,b \gt 0$$
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0 } \frac{a}{x}\left[ {\frac{x}{b}} \right]$$

So, I know that if x is $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ then the limit is $a\over [b]$
I couldn't figure out the solution for $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$

By the way, $[x]$ notation is equal to floor(x).

I'll be glad for a direction here

Comment: If $x<b$, then $\lfloor x/b \rfloor=0$.

Comment: OK, that's a good one, but what about the case when $x \ge b$?

Comment: @AndrePoole: you are making $x$ tend to $0$, hence ultimately you *have* $x<b$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Assume that $b>0$, prove that
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0^+ } \frac{a}{x}\left[ {\frac{x}{b}} \right]=0$$
and 
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0^{-} } \frac{a}{x}\left[ {\frac{x}{b}} \right]=\infty$$

Comment: Oh, that's easy actually. Got it now. Thanks

Comment: I'm such a n00b :)

Comment: @AndrePoole You're welcome.

Comment: @AndrePoole. So were we all.

Comment: I see now what is going inside the limit now. :+)